# Debian apturl alternative

Tags: debian, apt, package-management, browser, deb

Is there a Debian alternative to Ubuntu's `apturl`?
Basically, it enables `apt://` style URL compatibility with web browsers, for installing `.deb` packages via the APT protocol:
(i.e. `firefox apt:adobe-flashplugin?channel=$distro-partner`, etc.)

Comment: There used to be `aptlinex` but that was discontinued, looking at the Debian WIKI can't seem to find an alternative.

Comment: @Hunter.S.Thompson Yeah, I spent some time looking. Went through the the first few pages of Google search results until nothing was on topic. I don't get why it's not just available in the Debian repos.